# 405 (Method Not Allowed) Laravel & Node & Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Im trying to send post request from my node.js side. My node file

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = domain + '/api/server';

const getRaffle = () => {
      axios.post('/giveaway/getRaffle')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            io.sockets.emit('setRaffle', res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

Web.php / api.php (it doesn't work in any of them. when im using api, i know i need to use /api)

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/server'], function() {
    Route::post('/getRaffle', 'GiveawayController@getRaffle');
  });
```

After this im getting error in terminal: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Thanks you for help!

Comment: If you make a api POST, PUT or DELETE request then you need to set the `csrf` token in your request header. You can set it globaly or in every single Request.

Comment: You had error with your endpoints, I sent you an answer

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, you're defining a route `/server/getRaffle` in api.php routes which means it will have `/api/server/getRaffle` URI. But in your Javascript code you're making a request to `/api/server/giveaway/getRaffle`. I suggest you double-check that.

You can check all defined routes with `php artisan route:list` command. If the route is not listed it's possible your routes are cached in which case you need to run `php artisan route:clear` to delete the route cache. Run `php artisan route:list` again to see if your route showed up now.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending request to

```
domain + '/api/server/giveaway/getRaffle'
```

However, you do not have this endpoint in your Laravel application. The code block that you write in your route file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/server'], function() {
    Route::post('/getRaffle', 'GiveawayController@getRaffle');
  });
```

maps to:

`/api/server/getRaffle` not `/api/server/giveaway/getRaffle`

Either change your js axios call code to:

axios.defaults.baseURL = domain + '/api/server';

```
const getRaffle = () => {
      axios.post('/getRaffle')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            io.sockets.emit('setRaffle', res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

or change your Laravel router file code to:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/server'], function() {
    Route::post('/giveaway/getRaffle', 'GiveawayController@getRaffle');
  });
```